# How to compile rmf_core using colcon build in ROS2 eloquent?

Tags: ros2, compile, colcon, build, fcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On running the build, the error stated that the **fcl package** not found when building package *rmf_traffic*.

Source from github: https://github.com/osrf/rmf_core

```
Starting >>> rmf_utils
Starting >>> rmf_dispenser_msgs
Starting >>> rmf_fleet_msgs
Starting >>> rmf_traffic_msgs
Starting >>> rmf_door_msgs
Starting >>> rmf_lift_msgs
Starting >>> cpp_pubsub
Starting >>> rmf_workcell_msgs
Starting >>> turtlesim
Finished <<< cpp_pubsub [0.28s]                                
Finished <<< turtlesim [0.95s]                                 
Finished <<< rmf_utils [2.69s]                                       
Starting >>> rmf_traffic                                                
--- stderr: rmf_traffic                                                     
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:415 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:593 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:26 (pkg_check_modules)


---
Failed   <<< rmf_traffic    [ Exited with code 1 ]
Aborted  <<< rmf_door_msgs                        
Aborted  <<< rmf_lift_msgs                        
Aborted  <<< rmf_dispenser_msgs                   
Aborted  <<< rmf_workcell_msgs                    
Aborted  <<< rmf_fleet_msgs                       
Aborted  <<< rmf_traffic_msgs                                          

Summary: 3 packages finished [26.3s]
  1 package failed: rmf_traffic
  6 packages aborted: rmf_dispenser_msgs rmf_door_msgs rmf_fleet_msgs rmf_lift_msgs rmf_traffic_msgs rmf_workcell_msgs
  1 package had stderr output: rmf_traffic
  3 packages not processed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343547/how-to-compile-rmf_core-using-colcon-build-in-ros2-eloquent?/) by [webvenky](https://answers.ros.org/users/22361/webvenky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2020-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally, when trying to build ROS packages from source (which includes ROS 1 and ROS 2), you'd follow a certain workflow, one of the steps of which would be the make sure all package dependencies are present.

An example workflow is described in #q252478 (ignore the specific versions of Ubuntu and ROS: it's a generic workflow).

The important step that takes care of dependencies is the `rosdep` invocation.

It would appear however that `rmf_traffic` does not state the dependency on `fcl` anywhere in its [package.xml](https://github.com/osrf/rmf_core/blob/197b74f4e0d4509ec52ed26e0e7ab34c13fae9c9/rmf_traffic/package.xml). Without that information, `rosdep` would not be aware of the dependency and cannot help you.

In this particular case, you'd have to investigate the `CMakeLists.txt` of each package, identify the used packages/libraries (ie: see which `find_package(..)` lines there are) and manually install the corresponding Ubuntu/Debian packages.

In addition: it would be nice if you could report this on [the issue tracker](https://github.com/osrf/rmf_core/issues) and it would be even nicer if, after you've identified all dependencies, you could update the package manifests with this information and then submit a Pull Request to `osrf/rmf_core` that would fix this for everyone.

Refer to the [catkin documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended) / Overview / Resolving dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html#resolving-dependencies) section in the Catkin documentation for information on which particular sections would need to be added to the manifests.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-02-07**:
:+1: to everything said above by @gvdhoorn

Looking at the issue tracker of the package can also give you hints. For example it looks like this issue has been reported and has a solution listed: https://github.com/osrf/rmf_core/issues/70#issuecomment-580602947